# remove method of select options is not working in all browser(javascript)

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I am using Dhtmlx and javascript where i need to remove all options and then add options in selectbox.

I did it. but it is not working in all browser e.g(mozila3.4)

```
var opts=orgFrmformsg.getOptions("msges");
var checkedRows = MsgSummary.getCheckedRows(0).split(",");
var v=opts.length;
while(v--){
    opts.remove(v);
}
```

can anybody give alternate for this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Still i did not find solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use as below mention,

```
var opts = orgFrmformsg.getOptions("msges");        
        for(x=0;x<opts.length;x++){      
         if(opts[x].selected){       
           opts.remove(x);
         }
        }
```

Comment: but i did same thing but again same problem with different browser